# Python: Check if a value is in HTML table

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have used BeautifulSoup to extract specific data from an HTML table, now I need to check if that data occurs elsewhere in the table, and if so capture that data as well.

More specifically, the last column of my table contains just dates. The most recent date is at the top of the column, and this date sometimes reoccurs in lower rows. I am trying to write an if loop to see: if that date occurs somewhere else in the table, capture it and the corresponding data in its row.

Here is my relevant code:

```
`rows = table.findAll("tr")[0:20]
 more_data = {'last_column' : []}
 for row in rows [1:2]:
     cols = row.findAll("td")[0:20]
 more_data['last_column'].extend(cols[4].stripped_strings)
 var1 = more_data['last_column']             #stores date 5/20 in variable
 str1 = ''.join(var1)                        #turns 5/20 from list to string`


`data_data = {'entire_last_column' : [] }
 for row in rows [0:20]:
     cols = row.findAll("td")[0:20]
     data_data['entire_last_column'].extend(cols[4].stripped_strings)
 var2 = data_data['entire_last_column']     #stores entire last column of dates in variable `


`#var2.count(str1)

if any(var1 in s for s in var2):
    print(s)`
```

The last few lines of code are my attempts at searching and capturing future occurrences of '5/20'. But even those fail.

I need to verify if '5/20' occurs again in the table, and if it does then I need all the data from that row, and if it doesn't then end.

Here is the HTML code:

```
`<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>FW: NEFS 2 Available Quota 5/21</title>
<link rel="important stylesheet" href="">
<style>div.headerdisplayname {font-weight:bold;}</style></head>
<body>
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" class="header-part1"><tr><td><b>Subject: </b>FW: NEFS 2 Available Quota 5/21</td></tr><tr><td><b>From: </b>Claire Fitz-Gerald <claire@capecodfishermen.org></td></tr><tr><td><b>Date: </b>5/21/2014 10:08 AM</td></tr></table><br>
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; "><meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 12 (filtered medium)"><!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]--><style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Tahoma;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book";
    panose-1:2 11 5 3 2 1 2 2 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Franklin Gothic Demi";
    panose-1:2 11 7 3 2 1 2 2 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;}
span.EmailStyle17
    {mso-style-type:personal;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:windowtext;}
span.title1
    {mso-style-name:title1;
    font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";
    color:#1F487E;
    font-weight:normal;}
span.EmailStyle19
    {mso-style-type:personal-reply;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#1F497D;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-size:10.0pt;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head><body lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple><div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'>Please see the below quota listings.<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'>Thanks,<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><div><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>Claire Fitz-Gerald<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><i><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></i></p><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-family:"Franklin Gothic Demi","sans-serif";color:#002776'>Cape Cod Commercial Fishermen's Alliance<o:p></o:p></span></b></p><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#DE3500'>~ Small Boats.&nbsp; Big Ideas. ~</span></b><b><span style='color:#DE3500'><o:p></o:p></span></b></p></div><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><div><div style='border:none;border-top:solid #B5C4DF 1.0pt;padding:3.0pt 0in 0in 0in'><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'>From:</span></b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'> David Leveille [mailto:nefs02@gmail.com] <br><b>Sent:</b> Wednesday, May 21, 2014 8:50 AM<br><b>To:</b> David Leveille<br><b>Subject:</b> NEFS 2 Available Quota 5/21<o:p></o:p></span></p></div></div><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:#1F487E'>AVAILABLE QUOTA FY 2014</span><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'><o:p></o:p></span></p><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="71%" style='width:71.28%'><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>ID <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Available Quota <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Live Weight Pounds <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Price <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Date Posted <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td></tr><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1724<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM COD<br>GOM HADD<br>GOM BB<br>GREYSOLE<br>DABS<br>GOM YT<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>2328<br>445<br>3007<br>850<br>3101<br>1995<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Package<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$9,000<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/20<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1578<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GBE COD<br>GBW COD<br>GB BB<br>GB YT<br>SNE BB<br>SNE YT<br>GOM BB<br>Whake<br>POLL<br>RED<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>538<br>5894<br>1755<br>243<br>490<br>153<br>3965<br>2727<br>9227<br>15060<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$1.00<br>$0.40<br>$0.20<br>$1.00<br>$0.45<br>$0.50<br>$0.15<br>$0.20<br>$0.01<br>$0.01<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/20<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>310<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GBE COD<br>GBW COD<br>DABS<br>WHAKE<br>POLL<br>RED<br>SNE BB<br>GOM BB<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>825<br>9033<br>1241<br>3120<br>65234<br>76610<br>1688<br>1195<br>2121<br>7285<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Package<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$15,000<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/20<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr style='height:23.25pt'><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>347<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>SNE BB<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>8,000<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$0.50<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/7<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1878A<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM COD<br>GOM HADD<br>SNE BB<br>GOM BB<br>GB BB<br>GREYSOLE<br>GOM YT<br>SNE YT<br>POLL<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>6188<br>635<br>3916<br>7873<br>6762<br>3358<br>9776<br>271<br>186550<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$1.95<br>$1.35<br>$0.50<br>$0.50<br>$0.20<br>$1.40<br>$1.20<br>$0.50<br>$0.01<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/12<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1878B<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GBE COD<br>GBW COD<br>GB YT<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1113<br>12186<br>850<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Package<br>$10,000<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/12<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr></table><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>David Leveille<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>II Northeast Fishery Sector Inc.<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>10 Witham Street<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Gloucester, MA. 01930<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Cell 978 375 3509<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Fax 978 281 1555<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Web <a href="http://nefs2.com/">http://nefs2.com/</a><o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><div class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'></body></html>
</body>
</html>
`
```

[Screenshot of entire data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVFYM.png)

Comment: Could you provide a sample input HTML demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Is that the HTML you were looking for? Sorry if I misunderstood your question and that's not what you were looking for

Comment: Yeah, I think so. This HTML contains 5/21 only. What is the end goal - what do you want to extract from this HTML? Thanks.

Comment: 5/21? Are you sure you don't mean 5/12? Because there is no 5/21 in my table. I added a picture of the table above. Ideally I want to take all the data that corresponds to the most recent date. In some cases, the most recent date will only be the first row but in this case the first date spans 3 rows. That's why I need an if loop of some kind to check if rows beneath the first one also have the same date. Is that clear enough? Tell me if I'm not providing enough info.

Comment: Okay, gotcha. Please provide the *complete* HTML of the table. I've got an idea.

Comment: I added the entire HTML code above, except for a huge chunk of it near the end that seemed to be just endless letters and numbers that appeared to be garbage. I can add that as well though if it's pertinent.

Comment: I think the HTML you've posted still does not contain multiple rows so we can reliably reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ideally, would be great to see the HTML of the table which is on the screenshot.

Comment: Ok ok ok I'll try to fix it asap. The screenshot is just a snippet of the table though, there are a few more rows, I'll post a pic of the entire table. And I'll also edit in the entire HTML code, I hope it fits, we'll soon see.

Comment: The entire data table can now be seen in the image above. And the HTML code I copy and pasted from the "view page source" page. That is the place to get it from right? Sorry for being a noob when it comes to HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd find all table rows and use [`max()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) with a custom `key` function to determine the "latest" record. The custom function would find the inner cell with the date inside and convert it to the `datetime.date()` in order to compare dates with one another:

```
import re
from datetime import date

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """your HTML here"""    

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

# get the table header label
label = soup.find("span", text=re.compile(r"^AVAILABLE QUOTA FY"))

# extract the year
year = int(re.search(r"\d{4}", label.get_text()).group(0))

table = label.find_next("table")
rows = table.find_all("tr")[1:]  # skipping header row


def get_date(row):
    last_column_cell = row.find_all("td")[-1]

    # extract month and day
    month, day = last_column_cell.get_text().split("/")
    return date(year=year, month=int(month), day=int(day))


# filter the row with the latest date
row = max(rows, key=get_date)

# print the value of every cell in the row
print([td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.find_all("td")])
```

The code is probably missing error-handling and should be further improved, but it works on the provided sample data, prints:

```
['1724', 'GOM CODGOM HADDGOM BBGREYSOLEDABSGOM YT', '2328445300785031011995', 'Package$9,000', '5/20']
```

---

Note that this would only find the row with the maximum date. If you want to take it further - find all rows with this date:

```
# get the value of the latest cell
latest_date_string = row.find_all("td")[-1].get_text().strip()

# print the value of every cell in the row
print([[td.get_text(strip=True) for td in date_string.find_parent("tr").find_all("td")]
       for date_string in table.find_all(text=latest_date_string)])
```

Comment: The only critique I have of that is the printout: the pounds, for example, are all one long string so they can't be differentiated. That's why I use "stripped_strings" because I was told "get_text" loses some of the formatting tags. I have a question apart from your code above though, I am wicked close to succeeding with my own code and would like to ask just one pretty simple question. I have 
`for s in var2
if s == str1:
print(s)
else:
pass`
But instead of `print(s)` I would like to print/grab the entire row. Capturing the corresponding row is what is holding me up.

Comment: I actually ended up getting it to work combining both our code. Thanks so much for being patient with a noob like me.